# Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now　発生

Tags: mysql

mysqlで以下のストアドプロシージャを登録し、callしたところ表題のエラーが発生しました

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS register_001;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `register_001`(
    OUT `exit_cd` INTEGER
)

BEGIN

-- 異常終了ハンドラ
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET exit_cd = 99;

SET @query = CONCAT("
    SELECT
        INDEX_NO
    FROM
        T_MSTR
")
;

PREPARE main_query FROM @query;
EXECUTE main_query;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE main_query;

SET exit_cd = 0;

END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

呼び出し
    call register_001(@exit_cd);

実行はphpmyadmin上、mysqlのバージョンは5.6となります

同期が取れていないということですが、原因の予測がつきません。
原因に心当たりの方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えて頂けると幸いです。

Comment: 原因はわからないのですが エラーの説明はリファレンスにありました。ご参考になれば。[B.5.2.14 コマンドは同期されていません](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/commands-out-of-sync.html)